# Pine-script How to draw Last Price Line using plot()

Tags: pine-script

The code below draws the Last Price Line/ line for the last traded price. It uses the line.new() function to create the line. How do I draw the same line using the plot() function?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

var line lastPriceLine = line.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
line.set_xy1(lastPriceLine, bar_index-50, close)
line.set_xy2(lastPriceLine, bar_index, close)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Last Traded price of the prior / previous day?

if so,

```
//@version=4
study("LTP", overlay = true)
getseries(val,TF,offset)=>
    VAL = security(syminfo.tickerid, TF, val[offset], false, true)

LTP = getseries(close,'D',1)         // 1 signifies the previous day
plot(LTP)
```

Comment: I meant I want exactly the same line produced by the code I posted above, but using plot() since I can't use fill() with line.new().

Comment: We can use an offset parameter in plot function (offset = -50) to start the plot 50 bars behind,  ...  but it wont draw a straight line of the last traded price starting from 50 bars behind, especially as the close value keeps on changing with each bar...

Comment: If I set offset=-50 and show_last=1, is it possible to extend the value 50 bars to the right to achieve the same line?